# Shortcut for executing several lines in RStudio

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

I'm using **`RStudio`** and normally run my code line by line, using <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In general this works fine but working `dplyr` I would like to run a whole code-section I wrote using the pipe-operator `%>%`,

For e.g. I'd like to execute the following code-section at once, at the best independently from the current cursor position within the piped codelines:

```
mtcars %>%
  filter(carb >= 2) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(mean.hp = mean(hp))
```

I could run this line by line or mark all lines and then press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> but both ways are some kind of annoying. Searching the internet and the RStudio-options available in "`Tools/Modify Keyboard Shortcuts`" I only found other options like running a whole section, that is starting at

```
# Example section--------------------
```

Comment: In these situations, I always select the block of code via mouse or keyboard and hit `Ctrl + Enter`. Maybe there is a better way, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place cursor anywhere in the code chunk and use <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> (hold down <kbd>Crtl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then push <kbd>↑</kbd> button). The first time the word in which the cursor is placed gets highlighted, then, when repeted, the whole chunk of code gets highlighted. If you have a nested loop or another nested structure this will highlight the whole innermost loop, then the second inner most loop etc.

When you have the code highlighted you can press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the code.

Comment: I think this is a fairly new feature. Try update Rstudio from the webpage. You won't get the newest version if you uptdate from within Rstudio.

Answer (score 3):

I use the sections feature of RStudio liberally (like you noted) - but you didn't mention the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T to run the section (all the code between # comment ---- or #### partitions).

```
# mutate ----

# rename ####

# filter ####

# summarize ####
```

Comment: Normally I use these sections like "chapters" for large partitions, so even though this shortcut may be useful it does not really help me the way I hoped...

Comment: Right, looks like Fridriksson's answer would work better:
Ctrl + Shift + Up or Down to select chunks
Ctrl + R (runs highlighted code) or Ctrl + Enter (runs highlighted lines)

see https://twitter.com/rstudiotips/statuses/710882801940234240 for animated example

Comment: Correction re Fridriksson's answer:
Ctrl + Shift + Up helps select blocks of code (separated by empty lines - doesn't work by chunks)
Ctrl + Shift + Down goes to the end of blocks of code

Answer (score 3):

In RStudio version 1.0.136 it's now the default behavior:

Press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> anywhere in a multi-line pipe command and it will be run entirely.

Comment: I don't like this new default behaviour: When I forget a brake in my code, this makes RStudio run the whole code until the end of the document which is really annoying. I disabled it in the global options in order to use the workaround described above.