# Execute from cursor to beginning of code block in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Say the cursor is placed just after `(cyl)`in RStudio (as in top screenshot). Is there a way to run from the beginning of the code block to the cursor (as in bottom screenshot)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortcut for executing several lines in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765198/shortcut-for-executing-several-lines-in-rstudio)

Comment: No that runs the whole code block. I need to run from the cursor to the start of the code block

Comment: As a workaround I place `quit(save="ask")` just above the line where the script should stop and `source` the script, then choose _cancel_. Does that help?

Comment: Maybe try: `ctrl+shift+home` - select all from where cursor is to the top, then `ctrl+enter` to run.

Answer (score 4):

Try `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`B`

This runs your code from document beginning to current cursor line.

Source: [RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts-in-the-RStudio-IDE)

Answer (score 0):

My workflow in this situation:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> (keep holding)
2. push <kbd>Arrow up</kbd> (release button)
3. push <kbd>Pos1</kbd>
4. Release all
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>